# qtcreator 3.5.1: beautify on every safe

Tags: qt-creator

I have installed ClangFormat as beautifier for qtcreator, and it works via the hotkey in qtcreator, but I want it to beautify all code-files on every safe.

According to http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-beautifier.html the option is under Tools > Options > Beautifier, but it ain't. The entire "General"-tab is missing. I guess the relevant option was moved

How do I tell Qt-Creator 3.5.1 to beautify on every safe?